# Why does Status.CLIENT_ERROR_UNAUTHORIZED in Restlet returns an EmptyRepresentation when post

Tags: restlet, restlet-2.0

The Post method in Restlet 2.x returns an EmptyRepresentation when Status.CLIENT_ERROR_UNAUTHORIZED, it does not do so in Get-method.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem. Could you give the code you use so I can make a try? I guess that you use the method `setStatus` but you shoud throw a `ResourceException` with this status code.

When using this code:

```
public class TestServerResource extends ServerResource {
    @Post
    public Representation test(Representation repr) {
        throw new ResourceException(Status.CLIENT_ERROR_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
}
```

I have the following response:

```
405 Method Not Allowed
<html>
<head>
  <title>Status page</title>
</head>
<body style="font-family: sans-serif;">
  <p style="font-size: 1.2em;font-weight: bold;margin: 1em 0px;">Method Not Allowed</p>
  <p>The method specified in the request is not allowed for the resource identified by the request URI</p>
  <p>You can get technical details <a href="http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.6">here</a>.<br>
  Please continue your visit at our <a href="/">home page</a>.
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it will help you.
Thierry